# Data Annotation for foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first

I have two classes

```
public class Project
{
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int ManagerID { get; set; }
   public int CoordID { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ManagerID")]
   public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("CoordID")]
   public virtual Employee Coord { get; set; }

}

public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public int EmpID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("ManagerID")]
   public virtual ICollection<Project> ManagerProjects { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("CoordID")]
   public virtual ICollection<Project> CoordProjects { get; set; }
}
```

The ManagerID and CoordID map to the EmpID column of the Employee table.
I keep getting an error for Invalid Columns becauce EF is not able to map correctly. I think it is looking for wrong column.

Comment: I think your example is wrong, `public virtual Worker Manager` should be `Employee`?

Comment: Asre you looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ForeignKey)? (You can use Fluent API to map when EF can't figure it out based on naming convention.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `InverseProperty` is used to refer to the related navigation property, not the foreign key, e.g.

```
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public int EmpID { get; set; }
   public int Name { get; set; }
   [InverseProperty("Manager")]
   public virtual ICollection<Project> ManagerProjects { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("Coord")]
   public virtual ICollection<Project> CoordProjects { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is there a reason why your names are ints and not strings?

Comment: Names are string that's a typo.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the correct syntac for InverseProperty.

Answer (score 0):

Best guess would be to use [fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#ForeignKey) in your context via `OnModelCreating`. By renaming the column, EF can't figure out the original object to map so it's confused. However, Fluent API allows you to manually specify the map using something like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

  protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.Manager)
      .WithMany(x => x.ManagerProjects)
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.ManagerID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
      .HasRequired(x => x.Coord)
      .WithMany(x => x.CoordProjects)
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.CoordID);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to know if I could do this without using Fluent API.